# Sent Real Ether via Rinkeby to Ledger Nano

Tags: metamask, rinkeby

I feel so stupid, MetaMask on MEW account has Rinkeby as my default account and I sent 3 real ether to my Ledger Nano. i see it up on etherium.io on the Network Rinkeby. How do I reverse this or get it out of the test network. I'm so new at this and don't even remember adding rinkeby to my MetaMask account let alone as my default account.
please help! thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5):

Things you do on Rinkeby or some other test network should have no effect on the live network. The same address can be used on different networks, but the coins an address may have on one network are independent of the coins the same address can have on another network.

So if you only sent the transaction on Rinkeby, the mainnet coins should still be where you left them.